# how to get values from a Text view android

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to store values from text view for example i am performing the following plus function like 5+6.Now i want to store 5 as value-1 and 6 as value-2.I only have one text view where i am displying like 5+6 in my project.I search a lot about my issue but could not found any proper solution. thanks

Comment: What do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String string =text.getText().toString();
String[] separated = string.split("+");
String firstValue=separated[0];
String secondValue=separated[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot solved my problem. This is exactly i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and you will able to get the addition of two numbers at once. .

```
String[] getText = textview.getText().split("\\+");
int total=0;
for(String s:getText){
    total+=Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

in the end of iteration total will give the final result.From this method it gives the total of any numbers of numbers.